# Why my token get shorten automatically when I try to access it from the url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, query-string

I got an app running on the url with query parameter

```
http://localhost:4205/?token=rO0ABXdJAAlhZG1pbi13ZWIAAAGBQW7DvQAAAAAAJDQwNDVkNWU2LWUwYzQtNDkyOC1iZjI5LTI0ZTgwOGNkZDIyZQAAAAAAAeecAAAAAA==#LxbtdufwktgB49NKgqDwH6yisPjSRHV/k0bXUt/0+z3rLB8vFr3uWX39pzC6uVz1KgVw89S9Vku7cQp1Q1YZrQ==
```

So since I am using `react Router DOM`. I got the token by using a method from `react Router DOM`

```
const tokenFromQuery = searchParams.get('token');
```

this will search for a query token.

What happen is that when I try to `console.log` the token got from `tokenFromQuery` & which I copy from url `origin token`. These got different lengths

```
console.log(tokenToPass.length);

console.log('rO0ABXdJAAlhZG1pbi13ZWIAAAGBQW7DvQAAAAAAJDQwNDVkNWU2LWUwYzQtNDkyOC1iZjI5LTI0ZTgwOGNkZDIyZQAAAAAAAeecAAAAAA==#LxbtdufwktgB49NKgqDwH6yisPjSRHV/k0bXUt/0+z3rLB8vFr3uWX39pzC6uVz1KgVw89S9Vku7cQp1Q1YZrQ=='.length);
```

The result is `108` for token to pass and `197` from original token.

Why this happen? and

Answer (score 2):

because all after **#** in ***..AAAAAA==#Lxbtdufw..*** is no longer part of the variable in the url, then the token variable in the url is read until before the character #

you can encode the url before put it in the url, **encodeURIComponent** and then decode when you want to use it **decodeURIComponent**